# Is there a way to print if most of the answers are yes in a list, Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tkinter, printing

I'm creating a personality test, and I want the output to be "you are of this kind of personality" if most of the answers to the questions asked are yes. If not, it continues to ask questions about a different personality test.

I'm working with Python.

Comment: Can you add some reproducible code? Also show some proof of work: what did you try? What ideas do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to break your problem into smaller pieces. First, you need to count how many "yes" are in your list (`mylist.count("yes")`). Then, you need to check if that number is greater than the length of your list divided by two (`that_number >= len(mylist) / 2`).